# ReferenceError: window is not defined (Angular Universal)

Tags: angular, frontend, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object.79604 (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\universal\dist\project\server\main.js:26154:360416)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\universal\dist\project\server\main.js:254150:42)
at Module.20054
(C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\universal\dist\project\server\main.js:246050:68)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\universal\dist\project\server\main.js:254150:42)
at Object.83747
(C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\universal\dist\project\server\main.js:7138:12)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\universal\dist\project\server\main.js:254150:42)
at Object.72402
(C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\universal\dist\project\server\main.js:19325:13)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\universal\dist\project\server\main.js:254150:42)
at Object.90158
(C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\universal\dist\project\server\main.js:659:29)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\universal\dist\project\server\main.js:254150:42)

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:49936

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for but when working with `NextJS` you also get that kind of error and the answer is wrapping the `document` or `window` inside this:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  # write your code here
}
```

So if you have, for example, `document.querySelector()` around your app you only need to wrap it like this:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  document.querySelector()
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you use third party library and this error accurs because of that you have two options:

1- add this to your server.ts:

```
const MockBrowser = require('mock- browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser();

global.document = mock.getDocument();
global.window = mock.getWindow();
```

2- use that library only in browser:

in your ts file:

```
isBrowser = false;
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId){
isBrowser  = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
}
```

in your html file:

```
<thirdparty *ngIf="isBrowser"></thirdparty>
```

if you use window in your typescript:

```
if (this.isBrowser) {
window.....
}
```